# Bulk transcoding ISO/IMG to MP4/MKV

Tags: dvd, iso-image, mp4, handbrake, transcode

I need a tool/script to help me convert my collection of DVD's to MP4. I've started using Plex instead of playing each image-file directly and it's quite a pain in the butt to manually convert a collection of approx. 300 ripped DVD's.

What I'm looking for must be able to:

- 1) Scan a folder recursively for files
- 2) Add any ISO's and IMG's found to a queue
- 3) Mount and transcode the files to MP4
- 4) Place the new file in the same folder as the source

The tool/script must also be able to:

- A) Split each chapter into it's own file (fx. JAG is multi chapter DVD's with 4 episodes pr. disk). The same goes for CSI, NCIS and other series.
- B) Transcode with best possible audio and video settings (hardware wont be an issue)
- C) Include all audio- and subtitle tracks

I know this one will be a tough one, but I hope that you'll be able to help me. I guess that some tricks with handbrake could solve this but my attempts has not been very successful so far..
As stated previously hardware wont be an issue.
I'm open to your choice of OS as long as it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) is a great tool that will let you add a folder to convert.

Basically you have to do:

1. Do "Source / Open Folder" (and then select the folder of course)
2. Choose your conversion settings.
3. Do "Add To Queue" / "Add All".

It is recommended that you also tune the Automatic File Naming options.  You hae access to these settings from Tools / Options / Output files.

Comment: As far as I know, Handbrake isn't able to automatically mount ISO/IMG files. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I've recoded ISO files several times with Handbrake without the need to mount.
I've just tested that again.